# How to make Ctrl+alt 3rd level selector (Alt Gr) on Linux using Wayland?

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping, layout, wayland

How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> be the third level selector, similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Gr</kbd>, in **Wayland**?

All solutions found on the internet are very specific to Xorg and any key remapping software such as AutoKey or xbindkeys will not work in Wayland

This is very important in many European keyboard layouts as e.g. Alt Gr + (7-9) is very cumbersome to type otherwise

Comment: We are researching how to get AutoKey to work under Wayland. Currently, it does not work. Anyone who would like to help with this would be greatly appreciated.